# WhatsApp on two phones

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I installed WhatsApp 2.11.431 on LG G4 phone with Android 8.1 Oreo, made a backup with Helium and ADB, after that reinstalled the latest version, and everything is ok, continue working as usual.

To clone WhatsApp without verification, moved the backup to a phone with Android 4.0.4, installed WhatsApp 2.11.431 with Helium, restored the backup, reinstalled the latest WhatsApp, and works really well, both phones with same WhatsApp.

Yesterday, made the same steps on a Samsung Galaxy A6 with Android 10, but when installing the latest WhatsApp, it requested phone verification, but the other 2 phones continue working ok.

Made similar test with other WhatsApp numbers in the same Android 10, backup, restore in Android 4.0.4 and work well.

I am really lost. I want to move my WhatsApp to the Android 10 phones. I can't do the verification because I am out of my country and the line don't have signal.

Android 8.1 rooted, Android 10 not rooted, Android 4.0.4 not rooted.

Why a backup from Android 8.1 doesn't work in Android 10 but work in Android 4.0.4? Any help?

Comment: My guess is that Whatsapp uses AndroidKeystore which makes app cloning impossible. Android 4.0 does not support AndroidKeystore so that installation could be copied.

Comment: sorry but i think from 4.0 started to use AndroidKeystore

Comment: AndroidKeystore was [introduced in Android 4.3](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) but really usable was it starting with Android 5.

Comment: And is possible to replicate or clone the Key.. to and in the new phone?

Comment: If the key is in stored in AndroidKeyStore and the devices uses hardware security (Android security settings) then the key can't be exported no matter if you have root or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need phone verification to do authentication. If you can't do it, there is no solution for you except do phone verification.

Comment: This is not true, because i am using 2 phones with real whatsapp(no web) and in only one i made the verification